# How can I make a React component construct ...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

without actually using it in a render method?

I have a React component that only holds logic but still uses dispatch() from redux.  It is called `F1_Start`

```
// import F1_Start   from './F1_Start'
```

How do I get this file to run?

I tried

`new F1_Start()` but this did not seem to work.

I will eventually put it in a simple JavaScript class but then I would still need access to `dispatch()`

**Actual File**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class F1_Start extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    const options = {
      credentials: 'include'
    };
    fetch("/api/items", options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((results) => {
      this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateBookmarks', bookmarks: results});
      this.findStatus(results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.notLoggedIn();
      console.log('DEBUG: fetch /api/items error');
    });
  }

  findStatus = (results) => {
    if(results[results.length - 1].id_google){
      const user = results.slice(-1);
      this.loggedIn(user);
    } else {
      this.notLoggedIn();
    }
  }

  notLoggedIn = () => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // this.props.dispatch({ type: 'updateMenu', current: 'splash' });
    }, 4000);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // this.props.dispatch({ type: 'toggleSideBar' });
    }, 8000);
  }

  loggedIn = (user) => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'setUser', current: user[0] });
  }
}

export default connect()(F1_Start);
```

Answer (score 0):

React classes require a `render` method, and they require it to return a component, text, element, or `null`.

One way to do this is to make your component a simple wrapper:

```
// F1_Start
class F1_Start extends Component {
  ...constructor, fetchData, etc, plus:

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

// At (or near) the top level of your app
const App = props => (
  <Provider>
    <F1_Start>
      <RestOfTheApp />
    </F1_Start>
  <Provider>
)
```

The other way you could do this is, like you say, just use a JS class (without React), pass the Redux `store` into it, and access `store.dispatch` directly, instead of using `react-redux`'s `connect` HOC. Seems a little strange to do it that way, but it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "requires" a render method?  I got no error when I omitted it.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear: if you include a component in another component's `render` method, it requires a `render` method of its own. There's no real reason to extend `Component` if you're not going to include it in the component tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plain class F1_Start and call its methods in your parent component ParentComponent, Your plain class can return appropriate actions which you can dispatch from your parent connected component. This way you can keep your service logic separate.
Below is the code I could come up with.

Note : This code is not tested one and you need to change it as per your needs.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        this.fecthingData()
    }

    fecthingData() {
        let f1_Start = new F1_Start();  
        f1_Start.fetchData().then(actions => {
            actions.forEach(action => {
                this.props.dispatch(action);
            });
        })
    }
}
export default connect()(ParentComponent);


class F1_Start  {

     fetchData () {
         const actions = [];
         const options = {
            credentials: 'include'
        };
        return fetch("/api/items", options)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((results) => {
                actions.push ({ type: 'updateBookmarks', bookmarks: results });
                actions.push(this.findStatus(results));
                return actions;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('DEBUG: fetch /api/items error');
                actions.push(this.notLoggedIn());
                return actions;
            });
    }

    findStatus (results) {
        if (results[results.length - 1].id_google) {
            const user = results.slice(-1);
            return this.loggedIn(user);
        } else {
            return this.notLoggedIn();
        }
    }

    notLoggedIn() {
            return { type: 'updateMenu', current: 'splash' };
     }

    loggedIn(user){
        return { type: 'setUser', current: user[0] };
    }
}

export default F1_Start;
```